# SOT-227 mechanical attachment

Tags: mosfet, mounting-holes

In our latest project we need to switch a substantial current (as in 50-75A, less than 20V, at least). That would be a 2 FET load switch (back to back for polarity protection), fuse, current shunt, the usual stuff.

Now, it would be *almost* good for a triple copper PCB but a) triple copper is quite hard to do here and b) there's not really much margin and it would go hot. Board bus bars could be an option but they aren't easy to find either, as the 'special' board manufacture techniques with embedded bars or similar. As the PCB goes I'm stuck with a common dual layer double copper.

The current plan is using *real* bus bars and bolted components. Not the cheapest way but attractive since I've found almost everything I need (shunts and bolt fuses are quite common).

I'm stuck on the MOSFET packages, mostly because there is not a lot of documentation for these; SOT-227 seems to be the most common (the picture is from Microsemi but the part is Vishay, by the way)

[image: SOT-227 package]

The spacing and size for the terminals (they use M4 screw) just beg for the common 12×5mm copper busbar; it fits really well. The kelvin source and the gate can be attached easily with small lugs and *adequate* gate drive will be provided. On the other end of the bars standard lugs for the 25sqmm wires will be bolted (the compression lug itself is almost as big as the MOSFET!); so far the plan is good.

However the thing which puzzles me is the *height* of the assembly: the FETs will be greased and attached to the base sink-plate but 'standard' bar insulators are usually from 20-25mm up (and for good reasons, given that usually bars carry at least 400V).

What would be standard 'cabling' practice for the power terminal in these components? I actually found the required 12mm insulators from some manufacturers but I fear I'm missing some piece in the intended use of these MOSFETs.

ADD AFTER FURTHER RESEARCH

It seems that one popular way is to to screw them on circuit board. The issue is still how to pass the current in the copper board. Could I screw a conventional 12×5 busbar to the upside of the board? Not quite convinced about electrical contact

Comment: Is this a one-off or mass production? I was thinking to use obsolete capsules like that in the past too before my tutor educated me better to go with the industry's latest. That would be a string of SMDs in parallel. Just remember to use individual gate resistors.

Comment: with kelvin source it's recommended a driver for each MOSFET… the driver already has allowance for distinct charge and discharge resistors. Anyway it's mass production but before of all we need to build the prototype

Comment: SOT-227 does not ooze future-proof... Compare how many suppliers you have to choose between that and the equivalent SMD part.

Comment: That kind of dissipation is handled either by THT like the TO247 and TO3P or by some rare top-dissipation SMD part (like the Ixys/Littelfuse SMPD). That however turn back to *how* to pass 70A in a PCB. The TO and SOT seem more available than the special SMD packages